# Umbraco user not being saved

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco7

When attempting to create a new user (or save an existing), we are getting the error message in Umbraco 7.5.11

> Sections is a mandatory field

Even though there are values selected in the section element of the user profile

What is making Umbraco think there is no value selected? There is nothing in the JS console or anything obvious in the error log

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you running any packages that have added extra sections?

Comment: Can u Attach Some screen shots

Comment: screenshots of error added

Comment: No packages running that have extra sections